# friendly timthumb URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I currently have the following htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# redirect all calls to index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.site.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

which redirects non www links to www, and then after that for files and directories that don't exist it sends them to the index file. I have written a line that should create a friendly URL for using timthumb. Ive tried a few variations and tried it in a few places and still can't get it to work.

> RewriteRule ^thumb/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$
>   /_includes/thumb.php?src=images/case/$1&w=$2&h=$3 [L]
>
> or
>
> RewriteRule ^thumb/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$
>   /_includes/thumb.php?src=$1&w=$2&h=$3 [L]

I would appriciate any suggestions, thankyou.

Comment: Another Suggestion : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720646/timthumb-htaccess-rewrite/18078000#18078000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer was in putting the image last, and removing the possibilty of having slashes in the image path. Also added a line to negate the index.php redirect for requests to the thumb folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# redirect all calls to index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.site.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(thumb) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
      RewriteRule ^thumb/c/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) _includes/thumb.php?src=../images/case/$3&h=$2&w=$1


</IfModule>
```

New lines have been indented further

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like this :-

```
RewriteRule ^thumbnail/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z])/(.*) _includes/timthumb.php?w=$1&h=$2&a=$3&src=$4
```