# Timthumb htaccess rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, timthumb

Since like a day, my timthumb stopped working

however did figure out that it has probably to do with the modsecurity.

So the following, which worked untill a day ago.

http://www.HOST.com/wp-content/themes/THEME/scripts/timthumb.php?src=http://www.HOST.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/image.jpg&w=70&h=50&zc=1&q=100

Now only works using

http://www.HOST.com/wp-content/themes/THEME/scripts/timthumb.php?src=/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/image.jpg&w=70&h=50&zc=1&q=100

Tried putting this in my htaccess, but no change

```
# WPhtc: Begin Custom htaccess
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(timthumb) [NC]
RewriteRule ^scripts/timthumb.php?src=/(.*)x(.*)/r/(.*) scripts/timthumb.php?src=http://www.HOST.com/$3&h=$2&w=$1&c=1
# WPhtc: End Custom htaccess
```

Comment: SOLVED by HAVING HOSTGATOR, whitelist domain in MODSECURITY!, `$thumbnail = parse_url($src, PHP_URL_PATH);` would of been the other option, not using htaccess

Answer (score 2):

Using TimThumb for your images, can lead to some.. messy looking (and lest face it, unattainable) code. Observe..

```
<img alt="Camping" src="/timthumb.php?src=/images/feb/image_001.jpg&amp;w=250&amp;h=250&amp;" />
```

Why not take the messy out of it and use some funky .htaccess redirects?

```
<img alt="Camping" src="/images/feb/250/image_001.jpg" />
```

Doesn’t that look much better? Your wonderful camping image is now set to 250 pixels in width with the height being maintained at the correct ratio.

TimThumb htaccess rewrite
It is very easy and simple to achieve this! Update your .htaccess file, Like so.

```
# With your other RewriteCond rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(images) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R,L]

# Width
RewriteRule ^images/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9.]+)?$ /tt.php?src=/images/$1/$3&amp;w=$2
```

If you don’t have any sort of folder system and all your images are just thrown into the images folder, you can just use the following

```
RewriteRule ^images/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9.]+)?$ /tt.php?src=/images/$2&amp;w=$1
```

[Source](http://blog.davidcumberland.com.au/coding/easy-timthumb-htaccess-rewrite-urls/)

Comment: Although that looks nice, that would not resize images to the wanted size as does timthumb, there for I would have to do lots more recoding (adding width height) then I would like to.